# How to extract NuPlayer from AOSP and use it for HTTP Live Stream playback in downloadable app

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-mediaplayer, android-source, stagefright

I need some modifications to `NuPlayer` and to use it in my downloadable app.

Any suggestions on how to copy & reuse `NuPlayer` sources?

Should I instantiate `NuPlayerDriver` (`framework\base\media\libmediaplayerservice\nuplayer\NuPlayerDriver.cpp`) and use its methods or directly `NuPlayer` (`framework\base\media\libmediaplayerservice\nuplayer\NuPlayer.cpp`)?

From what I see, I need `NuPlayerDriver` because of `Looper` / `Message` / `Handler` stuff, though can I just use `NuPlayer` without this?

Edit: Is it better to build NuPlayer static library with AOSP build framework or just copy sources and build with NDK? The same is for the final downloadable player app, should I fully build it as part of AOSP build or use the NDK?

Comment: If your app is an `android` app, wouldn't it be better to instantiate a `NuPlayer` through `MediaPlayer` and interact with the same instead of copying the sources? Could you please elaborate a little on the need to copy the sources?

Comment: I need to encrypt media packets so player will first need to decrypt them. If I "own" NuPlayer, I can get the decryption keys from the server and decrypt content before playback.

Comment: If your objective is a secure playback, wouldn't it be better to employ `MediaDRM`, `MediaCodec` modules and build your own player. Alternatively, you could look into the existing framework where `DRMExtractor` is employed for ES based DRM as in here: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/MediaExtractor.cpp#84 where the decryption happens inside the extractor or for container based it is handled within file read as in here: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/FileSource.cpp#106

Comment: I was already looking at MediaDrm framework, however I need to have downloadable player app, so I can not install MediaDrm plugins. For that reason I am looking at possibility of extracting NuPlayer and/or parts of stagefright framework and reusing it in my player app. I presume the DRMExtractor you mention also requires changes to libstagefright.so?

Comment: @Sasha... `DRMExtractor` is already built in into `libstagefright.so`, but would require plugins for decrypting. Please check the `read` method as in here: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/DRMExtractor.cpp#143 . If this doesn't help you, I will post an answer to pickup the `NuPlayer` and related sources. From your comments, I feel `DRMExtractor` based mechanism may be more suited for your app.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh for info, however the plugin approach won't work for me. I think picking up NuPlayer and dependencies would only work in my scenario, so any info in that direction will be great.